# Pandas df.drop_duplicates() isn't dropping duplicates; df.sort() isn't sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure what is happening but neither sort by date nor drop_duplicates() are working for my dataset.

I am concatenating two datasets, as follows:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
test_file = pd.read_csv('test_df.csv',index_col=0,encoding="utf_8")
test_file = test_file.reset_index(drop=True)

#compare csv with new results
df3 = pd.concat([df,test_file])
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)
df3.groupby(list(df3.columns)).filter(lambda df3:df3.shape[0] == 1)
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df3.sort('_date')
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()
```

This doesn't appear to be deleting duplicates at all -- or sorting by date.

For example, later in the file:

```
462,,,,,,51.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37.0,,,2015-06-22 00:00:00,General Election: Walker vs. Clinton,NBC News/Wall St. Jrnl
463,,40.0,,,,48.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2015-06-22 00:00:00,General Election: Bush vs. Clinton,NBC News/Wall St. Jrnl
```

And towards the top:

```
222,,,,,,51.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37.0,,,2015-06-22 00:00:00,General Election: Walker vs. Clinton,NBC News/Wall St. Jrnl
223,,40.0,,,,48.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2015-06-22 00:00:00,General Election: Bush vs. Clinton,NBC News/Wall St. Jrnl
```

As you can see these rows are the same except for index. And the dates are the same, yet the date sorting isn't sorting. Could it be a type issue?

Column names:

```
,Biden,Bush,Carson,Chafee,Christie,Clinton,Cruz,Fiorina,Graham,Huckabee,Jindal,Kasich,O'Malley,Pataki,Paul,Perry,Rubio,Sanders,Santorum,Trump,Walker,Warren,Webb,_date,_poll,_pollname
```

Ideas?

Comment: A few things: you need to assign your `groupby`  statement to another `df3` variable and add in an `as_index=False` to remove the redundant  `reset_index()`.  `groupby()` returns a groupby object and does not operate on the data frame in place. As far as the sort, are the values in the `_date` column actually date time objects? Once these issues are fixed/confirmed, try  executing `drop_duplicates()` again.

Comment: Did this produce the result you wanted?

Comment: @bleh Let me give it a try..

Comment: `df3 = df3.groupby(list(df3.columns), as_index=False).filter(lambda df3:df3.shape[0] == 1)` This deletes all rows. Trying to fix.

Comment: I don't believe the groupby method is working; it seems like an alternative to drop_duplicates, anyway.

Comment: `df3['_date']  = pd.to_datetime(df3['_date'])` solved the date sorting. Just the dupes now.

Comment: Excellent, what were you trying to accomplish with the group by? It seemed like some sort of column filter.

Comment: Looks as though drop_duplicates is also now working.

Comment: @bleh I think that is a deprecated alternative way to drop duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81341/discussion-between-bleh-and-in-code-veritas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, the dates were actually string dates and not date time objects.

The simple fix was:

```
df3['_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['_date'])
```

`drop_duplicates()` also began to function properly after this change.

Final code:

```
#compare csv with new results
df3 = pd.concat([df,test_file])
df3['_date']  = pd.to_datetime(df3['_date'])
df3 = df3.sort('_date')
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)
```